# Are there any trapdoor slot video cards for a non-tower Amiga 1200?

Tags: amiga, video, amiga-1200

Are there any trapdoor slot video cards for a non-tower Amiga 1200 ?

(That excludes Zorro expansion cards, PCI mediator cards and BlizzardPPC+BVision - as all of those require tower case,
also excludes upcoming vampire for A1200, indivision and scandoublers )

If not - then what would it take to make one ?

This is partially inspired by recently released video card for A2000 by mntmn.

Comment: When released, would the Vampire 1200 count?

Comment: @rrrzx I'm asking about existing products, I'm aware of upcoming vampire (I have the v2 for my 600 already).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Indivision AGA doesn't attach to the trapdoor slot, but it also doesn't need a tower case because it attaches to the Lisa chip. (In a way, this is better than a trapdoor video card because it leaves the trapdoor available for accelerators.) It gives you video modes up to 1280x1024x256 colors, but for me it glitches at that resolution so I use 1024x768 or 1280x720.

But it has no 3-D support. Basically it's just a scan doubler with additional resolutions and DVI output.

Edit: I change my answer: BlizzardVisionPPC + Blizzard603e/e+ + an upgraded power supply and maybe some extra vents in your desktop case. This has 24-bit color and 3D, and goes up to 1280x1024x24bpp or 1600x1200x16bpp.

Comment: Yes, but that's not a video card itself (although it's close).

Comment: What are you looking for in a video card?

Comment: roughly what RTG (picasso96 perhaps) offers - 24bit color, higher resolutions etc. And ideally hardware acceleration, because at 1024x768 AGA chip with Indivision gets pretty slow.

Comment: Then I change my answer: BlizzardVisionPPC + Blizzard603e/e+ + an upgraded power supply and maybe some extra vents in your desktop case. This has 24-bit color and 3D, and goes up to 1280x1024x24bpp or 1600x1200x16bpp.

Comment: fair enough, even though it's basically unobtainable that seems to match what I was looking for. Does it work in both 68k and PPC modes ?